# In Android, can a cookie set by CookieManager.setCookie be read by another App?

Tags: android, kotlin, cookies

In Android, if an App sets a cookie in a webview using `CookieManager.setCookie`, can another App of a different developer access the content of that cookie?

If it is technically doable, is it against any Android policies to share data across apps like this?

Answer (score 3):

No. The cookies are stored in SQLite database in the application's private directory. Other apps cannot directly access them. 
More details you can find in the android.webkit package source files:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2269d1572e5fcfb725ea55f5764d8c3280d69f6d/core/java/android/webkit

Answer (score 1):

every app is running in sandbox, you can't inspect data stored in one app (`SQLite`, `SharedPreferences`, files since [Scoped Storage](https://betterprogramming.pub/android-scoped-storage-demystified-3024a062ba24) introduction) from another app until you provide some own communication mechanism (broadcast, contentprovider, aidl etc.) for passing data between them on both sides